# ¿Cómo se produce y cómo evitar el error MySQL shutdown unexpectedly?

Tags: mysql

Cuando inicio mysql me da el siguiente error:

```sh
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
```

He investigado un poco y sé cómo se soluciona, y dicen que se debe a que el puerto está ocupado o algo así. El problema está en que el error aparece cada 4 días después de solucionarlo, y lo que quiero saber es cómo hacer para que no ocurra nunca más.

PD:Lo soluciono de la siguiente manera:

- Rename the folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old (you can use any name)
- Create a new folder mysql/data
- Copy the content that resides in mysql/backup to the new mysql/data folder
- Copy all your database folders that are in mysql/data_old to mysql/data (skipping the mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders from data_old)
- Finally copy the ibdata1 file from mysql/data_old and replace it inside mysql/data folder
- Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel

Comment: Primero encuentra la causa original y da una solucion para esa causa, ya que el error te dice que puede ser causado por varias cosas y para solucionarlo para siempre, tendrías que anticiparse a cualquiera de las situaciones (bastante generales, sería imposible). Si encuentras la causa que te tira el server cada 4 días, al menos ahí ya no lo hará. Saludos.

Comment: ***se debe a que el puerto está ocupado o algo así***, pues no es muy descriptiva esa causa. Si el puerto está ocupado, la forma de solventarlo puede variar. Podrías cambiar el puerto por defecto de MySQL, para ello debes editar el archivo de configuración `my.conf` (si mal no recuerdo). O podrías simplemente averiguar qué servicio o programa hace uso del puerto de MySQL y evitar que lo haga. Todo esto suponiendo que se trate de *puertos o algo así*

Comment: Y cómo lo estás solucionando actualmente? Es que no sabemos por qué te estás encontrando ésto? Tienes algún servicio del sistema operativo confgurado para iniciarlo automáticamente? La respuesta a tu pregunta depende de los detalles que debes añadir al [edit] tu pregunta

Comment: Esa solución es exageradísima y no arregla ningún problema. Sólo restaura lo más reciente que haya en backup (puedes perder datos que no se alcanzaron a guardar) y reinicia todo. Es necesario revisar en los logs por qué se está deteniendo el servicio. Es windows? Revisaste el visor de eventos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si realmente es lo que dices y la ejecución falla porque el puerto esta ocupado, es tan fácil como crear un script en bash que deje el puerto libre y luego inicie la base de datos:

```
# !/bin/bash 
fuser -k 3306/tcp
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Cambia la tercera línea por la que uses para iniciar tu base de datos.
Guarda el archivo con extensión '.sh' y para ejecutarlo abre un terminal y ejecuta la instrucción:

```
bash /path/to/scriptname
```

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes workbench u otra cosa, ve a `xampp` dale a config busca `mysql80` detenlo e intenta ahora arrancar el mysql desde `xampp`

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).